# Using these while referring to one person?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> "I ignore these people when I see them."
>
> "I ignore this type of person when I see one."

Let's say you watch a rude person on a video and you say one of those two sentences, is that ok outside of informal speech?

Because if you are referring to one person, you shouldn't use these. Also, the second sentence might be wrong, because "one" refers to this type of person. "I ignore this type of person when I see one of this type." Can "one" refer to "one of this type" or is it just plain wrong? How would you say this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are acceptable.

In the first case, "these people" implies the set of people of which this one is a member.

In the second case, "this type of person" refers to the specific person as a representative member of the larger set.